# Eclipce Could not create the view: com.ibm.etools.ui.navigator.SDExplorer

Tags: java, eclipse

i just installed eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64 and my windows is 7 64bit and i installed jdk-7u25-windows-x64 and jre-7u25-windows-x64   as i want to start learning and using Mobile Application Development with IBM Worklight Foundation V6.2 but this error is shown up to me when i unzipped the eclipse file and run the eclipse application without doing anything.[The Eclipse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y3yK.png)

Comment: what should i do ?? what's wrong?

Comment: Try with Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try with Java 1.6 instead and/or with Eclipse Kepler instead of Juno.

Answer (score 0):

Replying for the people who might end up in this thread for solution.

It because of old workspace setting related to jdt. Either delete it or create a new workspace and issue must be resolved.

Tried and tested...